GDI flicker when animating bitmap
I am trying to remove flicker from my bitmap animation in GDI. It is a rainbow animation. The animation animates smoothly but the bitmap buttons flicker.
I tried InvalidateRect() but the flicker still happens. Here is my stripped down code. ImageData is my static rainbow bitmap's pixel's value. I animate it by changing the all the elements to their next position.
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

HDC hdcMem;
HBITMAP hbmMem;
HANDLE hOld;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC hdc;
HBITMAP Membitmap;

int WIDTH = 350;
int HEIGHT = 500;

std::deque<int> imageData =
    {0xFB017D, 0xFB0278, 0xFB017D, 0xFC0280, 0xFB027A, 0xFB027A, 0xFB017C, 0xFA0175, 0xFC026E, 0xFC026C, 0xFC036B, 0xFC0266,
     0xFC0263, 0xFC015E, 0xFC025B, 0xFB015A, 0xFB0351, 0xFB0351, 0xFC014E, 0xFC024C, 0xFC0249, 0xFC0146, 0xFC0242, 0xFC0241, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0235, 0xFD0132, 0xFD022D, 0xFD0329, 0xFC0226, 0xFC0228, 0xFC0323, 0xFC021D, 0xFC0319, 0xFE0219, 0xFD0116, 0xFD0213, 0xFC020E, 0xFC020C, 0xFC030B, 0xFB0206, 0xFB0304, 0xFB0303, 0xF90403, 0xF90304, 0xF90306, 0xFD0002, 0xFE0606, 0xFB0905, 0xF90C04, 0xFC1005, 0xFD1104, 0xFB1404, 0xFC1906, 0xF81A03, 0xFB2004, 0xFB2203, 0xFA2402, 0xFA2805, 0xF82A05, 0xF82D04, 0xFB3204, 0xFB3705, 0xF93A06, 0xFA3D06, 0xFC3F05, 0xFF4105, 0xFE4203, 0xFC4604, 0xFB4A06, 0xFB5106, 0xFC5207, 0xFB5406, 0xFC5707, 0xFB5904, 0xFB5B03, 0xFC5D02, 0xFC5E03, 0xFC6303, 0xFB6504, 0xFC6804, 0xFB6E04, 0xFC7205, 0xFC7605, 0xFC7905, 0xFD7A04, 0xF97B02, 0xFC7E03, 0xFB8102, 0xFB8402, 0xFC8A05, 0xFC8C04, 0xFA8F03, 0xFD9204, 0xFB9703, 0xFC9804, 0xFC9A03, 0xFC9D03, 0xFBA103, 0xFCA603, 0xFDAA06, 0xFEAD06, 0xFBAE06, 0xFDB306, 0xFDB805, 0xFCBC05, 0xFBBD06, 0xFAC005, 0xFCC304, 0xFEC502, 0xFACC05, 0xFBCD05, 0xFBD007, 0xFDD305, 0xFAD403, 0xFAD703, 0xF9DA03, 0xFBDC05, 0xFDE104, 0xFAE202, 0xF8E703, 0xFBED06, 0xFDEF06, 0xFCEE05, 0xFAF005, 0xFAF307, 0xFAF503, 0xF8F603, 0xF7F605, 0xF2F504, 0xF0F505, 0xEDF605, 0xECF703, 0xEBF904, 0xE6FC06, 0xE1F903, 0xDDF904, 0xDCFC05, 0xD7FB05, 0xD4FC06, 0xD3FB05, 0xCEF801, 0xCEF703, 0xCCF803, 0xC8FA05, 0xC2FA03, 0xBEFA04, 0xBAFA05, 0xB6FB04, 0xB3F902, 0xB4FA04, 0xB3F903, 0xB0FA03, 0xADFB05, 0xAAFC06,
     0xA2FA05, 0x9EF904, 0x9CFB07, 0x98FA05, 0x94F802, 0x92F703, 0x8FF903, 0x8DFB06, 0x89FB06, 0x84FA04, 0x82FA03, 0x83FB06, 0x7DF905, 0x77F905, 0x77FA06, 0x77FA08, 0x73F906, 0x6EFA03, 0x6AFB02, 0x6AFA04, 0x68F802, 0x68FA04, 0x63F904, 0x5DF703, 0x58F804, 0x56FA05, 0x52FA04, 0x53F903, 0x4DF903, 0x4AFA04, 0x47F905, 0x47F905, 0x45F806, 0x3FF902, 0x3BF901, 0x3BFC05, 0x36FA02, 0x32F803, 0x2EF804, 0x2CF906, 0x27F904, 0x27F904, 0x26FA05, 0x1FFB03, 0x1CFB04, 0x18FA03, 0x14FA04, 0x10FA05, 0x0CFA04, 0x0CFA04, 0x0BFB04, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x03FA0B, 0x03FA0B, 0x03FA0D, 0x04FA0F, 0x04FA13, 0x03FA15, 0x04FA19, 0x04FA1B, 0x02F922, 0x03FA23, 0x03FA27, 0x03F92A, 0x04F92F, 0x05FA33, 0x04FA37, 0x04F939, 0x05F93F, 0x06FA42, 0x05FA43, 0x05FA47, 0x04FB4B, 0x04FA4F, 0x04FA51, 0x05FA54, 0x04FA57, 0x04FA57, 0x04FA5B, 0x03FB5D, 0x03FA61, 0x03FA65, 0x04FA67, 0x04FA69, 0x04F96D, 0x04F96E, 0x04F970, 0x04F976, 0x04F97A, 0x05F980, 0x04F982, 0x04F984, 0x05F988, 0x07FB8A, 0x05FB8E, 0x03FA8F, 0x03FA92, 0x04FB93, 0x06FB96, 0x06FB96, 0x05FA9B, 0x05FA9F, 0x03FAA1, 0x04FAA5, 0x04F9A9, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBB5, 0x04FBB7, 0x04FAB9, 0x04FABB, 0x04F8C2, 0x05F9C5, 0x03F9C6, 0x03F9C8, 0x04F9CE, 0x02F7CC, 0x05F7CF, 0x06F7D4, 0x03F6D8, 0x04F8DE, 0x05F8E4, 0x02F7E5, 0x03F8E7, 0x03F8E7, 0x03F8E9, 0x03F7ED, 0x04F7F1, 0x04F6F7, 0x04F6FA, 0x03F4FB, 0x05F1FF, 0x02EEFC, 0x05EEFD, 0x04E9FC, 0x05E8FB, 0x06E7FD,
     0x04E1FB, 0x05E2FC, 0x06DDF9, 0x02D6FE, 0x01D5FA, 0x04D6F7, 0x04D1FE, 0x05CEF8, 0x06CBF6, 0x03C4FD, 0x05C2FC, 0x02BEFB, 0x03BCFC, 0x05BBFD, 0x04B5FB, 0x03B1FA, 0x04B0FC, 0x04AEFC, 0x02ABFC, 0x04ABFC, 0x03AAFB, 0x03A7FC, 0x04A4FC, 0x049FFC, 0x059BFC, 0x0498FC, 0x0592FE, 0x028FFB, 0x038BFB, 0x0389FC, 0x0586FD, 0x0482FB, 0x057FFC, 0x057FFE, 0x057CFE, 0x0277FB, 0x0474FC, 0x0671FD, 0x056BFC, 0x0468FC, 0x0468FE, 0x0466FF, 0x0361FE, 0x035BFB, 0x0659FD, 0x0354FB, 0x0354FD, 0x0654FE, 0x034FFA, 0x064EFA, 0x054AFD, 0x0446FC, 0x0343FC, 0x0442F9, 0x053FF8, 0x043BF7, 0x0338FA, 0x0536FF, 0x0734FF, 0x0530FB, 0x042DFB, 0x0528FC, 0x0223FA, 0x0521FE, 0x0720FF, 0x051DFD, 0x0517FD, 0x0415FB, 0x0412FB, 0x030FFB, 0x040DFC, 0x0509FE, 0x0406FB, 0x0203FB, 0x0201FC, 0x0402FD, 0x0601FD, 0x0600FE, 0x0302FD, 0x0402FD, 0x0801FC, 0x0B02FD, 0x0E02FA, 0x1502FC, 0x1A01FD, 0x1C01FC, 0x1C02FB, 0x2003FD, 0x2303FC, 0x2601FC, 0x2A01FB, 0x2B02FC, 0x2C02FC, 0x3001FD, 0x3201FB, 0x3801FC, 0x3A02FB, 0x3E03FD, 0x4202F9, 0x4601FC, 0x4A02FC, 0x4D02FD, 0x4D02FB, 0x4E02FA, 0x5202F7, 0x5501F7, 0x5B00FB, 0x5E02FB, 0x6303FB, 0x6502FB, 0x6701FA, 0x6802FB, 0x6B02FC, 0x6A01FC, 0x6C02FC, 0x7002FB, 0x7502FD, 0x7B02FD, 0x8002FC, 0x8401FC, 0x8602FD, 0x8902FE, 0x8D02FD, 0x8D02FD, 0x8F03FC, 0x9102FC, 0x9402FB, 0x9801FC, 0x9B02FB, 0x9E03FD, 0xA302FD, 0xA500FA, 0xAC03FE, 0xAC02FB, 0xAE01FB, 0xB203FC, 0xB500FB, 0xBC02FD, 0xBD00FC, 0xC001FE, 0xC403FE, 0xC502FC, 0xC602FA, 0xCA02FB, 0xCD02FA,
     0xCD02FA, 0xD402FB, 0xD702FC, 0xD902FD, 0xDD02FC, 0xE102FB, 0xE402FC, 0xE802FB, 0xEC01FC, 0xED00FC, 0xF202F9, 0xF601FE, 0xF602F7, 0xF600FF, 0xF703F8, 0xFA02F9, 0xFD02F0, 0xFD02F0, 0xFD02F0, 0xFC01EE, 0xFC01EF, 0xFD03DF, 0xFC02E0, 0xFC02E0, 0xFC02DE, 0xFD03D9, 0xFC02D8, 0xFB03CD, 0xFD02CE, 0xFD02CD, 0xFD03C7, 0xFD01C6, 0xFC02BC, 0xFC02BE, 0xFB01BA, 0xFB02B4, 0xFD02B3, 0xFD02B3, 0xFC01B2, 0xFC02AE, 0xFC02AC, 0xFC01A8, 0xFC02A4, 0xFC02A1, 0xFC039F, 0xFC039F, 0xFB029E, 0xFC0298, 0xFB0294, 0xFC018F, 0xFC018E, 0xFB0278, 0xFB0083, 0xFB017C, 0xFC0377, 0xFB0081, 0xFB017C, 0xFB0373, 0xFA007B, 0xFC026E, 0xFC026C, 0xFC036B, 0xFC0266, 0xFC0263, 0xFC015E, 0xFC025B, 0xFB015A, 0xFB0351, 0xFB0351, 0xFC014E, 0xFC024C, 0xFC0249, 0xFC0146, 0xFC0242, 0xFC0241, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0235, 0xFD0132, 0xFD022D, 0xFD0329, 0xFC0226, 0xFC0228, 0xFC0323, 0xFC021D, 0xFC0319, 0xFE0219, 0xFD0116, 0xFD0213, 0xFC020E, 0xFC020C, 0xFC030B, 0xFB0206, 0xFB0304, 0xFB0303, 0xF90403, 0xF90304, 0xF90306, 0xFD0002, 0xFE0606, 0xFB0905, 0xF90C04, 0xFC1005, 0xFD1104, 0xFB1404, 0xFC1906, 0xFB1A04, 0xFD2005, 0xFC2304, 0xFB2503, 0xFA2805, 0xFA2C07, 0xFA2F06, 0xFE3507, 0xF93503, 0xF93704, 0xF83B04, 0xFB3E04, 0xFD4104, 0xFB4202, 0xFB4503, 0xFA4905, 0xF64C01, 0xF84E03, 0xF85103, 0xF95404, 0xFA5803, 0xFB5B03, 0xFD5E03, 0xFD5F04, 0xFC6303, 0xFB6504, 0xFC6804, 0xFB6E04, 0xFC7205, 0xFC7605, 0xFC7905, 0xFC7903, 0xFA7C03, 0xFD7F04, 0xFC8203, 0xFB8402, 0xFB8904, 0xFC8C04,
     0xF98E02, 0xFC9103, 0xFB9703, 0xFC9804, 0xFC9A03, 0xFC9D03, 0xFBA103, 0xFCA603, 0xFCA905, 0xFDAC05, 0xFBAE06, 0xFDB306, 0xFDB805, 0xFCBC05, 0xFBBD06, 0xFBBF05, 0xFCC304, 0xFEC502, 0xF8CA03, 0xFACC04, 0xFBD007, 0xFCD204, 0xFAD403, 0xFBD804, 0xFADB04, 0xFCDD06, 0xFDE104, 0xFAE202, 0xF8E703, 0xFBED06, 0xFDEF06, 0xFBED04, 0xF9EF04, 0xF9F206, 0xFAF503, 0xF8F603, 0xF7F605, 0xF2F504, 0xF0F505, 0xEDF605, 0xECF703, 0xEAF803, 0xE5FB05, 0xE0F802, 0xDDF904, 0xDBFB04, 0xD6FA04, 0xD3FB05, 0xD2FA04, 0xCEF801, 0xCFF804, 0xCDF904, 0xC7F904, 0xC1F902, 0xBDF903, 0xBAFA05, 0xB6FB04, 0xB5FA03, 0xB4FA04, 0xB2FA03, 0xAFF902, 0xACFA04, 0xA9FB05, 0xA1F904, 0x9EF904, 0x9BFA06, 0x98FA05, 0x94F802, 0x92F703, 0x8FF903, 0x8DFB06, 0x89FB06, 0x84FA04, 0x84FA04, 0x82FA05, 0x7CF804, 0x77F905, 0x76F905, 0x76F907, 0x73F906, 0x6DF902, 0x6AFB02, 0x6AFA04, 0x68F802, 0x67F903, 0x63F904, 0x5CF602, 0x58F804, 0x56FA05, 0x52FA04, 0x54FA04, 0x4DF903, 0x4AFA04, 0x47F905, 0x46F804, 0x43F906, 0x40FA03, 0x3CFA02, 0x3BFC05, 0x36FA02, 0x32F803, 0x2EF804, 0x2CF906, 0x27F904, 0x27F904, 0x25F904, 0x1FFB03, 0x1CFB04, 0x18FA03, 0x14FA04, 0x10FA05, 0x0CFA04, 0x0CFA04, 0x0BFB04, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x03FA0B, 0x03FA0B, 0x03FA0D, 0x04FA0F, 0x04FA13, 0x03FA15, 0x04FA19, 0x04FA1B, 0x02F922, 0x03FA23, 0x03FA27, 0x03F92A, 0x04F92F, 0x05FA33, 0x04FA37, 0x04F939, 0x05F93F, 0x06FA42, 0x05FA43, 0x05FA47, 0x04FB4B, 0x04FA4F, 0x04FA51,
     0x05FA54, 0x04FB55, 0x04FA57, 0x04FA59, 0x03FB5D, 0x03FA61, 0x03FA65, 0x04FA69, 0x04FA6B, 0x04F970, 0x04F96D, 0x04F779, 0x04FA73, 0x04F783, 0x05F97D, 0x04F889, 0x04F886, 0x04F887, 0x06FA89, 0x05FB8E, 0x03FA8F, 0x03FA92, 0x04FB93, 0x06FB96, 0x05FA95, 0x05FA9B, 0x05FA9D, 0x03FAA1, 0x04FAA5, 0x04F9A9, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBAD, 0x04FBB5, 0x04FBB7, 0x04FABB, 0x04FBB7, 0x04F8C5, 0x05F9C3, 0x03F9C6, 0x03F9C8, 0x04F9CE, 0x02F7CC, 0x05F7CF, 0x06F7D4, 0x03F6D8, 0x04F8DE, 0x05F8E4, 0x02F7E5, 0x03F8E7, 0x03F8E7, 0x03F8E9, 0x03F7ED, 0x04F7F1, 0x04F6F7, 0x04F6FA, 0x03F4FB, 0x05F1FE, 0x02EEFB, 0x05EEFD, 0x04E9FC, 0x05E8FB, 0x06E7FD, 0x04E1FB, 0x05E2FC, 0x06DDF9, 0x02D6FE, 0x02D6FB, 0x05D7F8, 0x04D1FE, 0x05CEF8, 0x06CBF6, 0x03C4FD, 0x05C2FC, 0x02BEFB, 0x03BCFC, 0x05BBFD, 0x04B5FB, 0x03B1FA, 0x04B0FC, 0x04AEFC, 0x02ABFC, 0x04ABFC, 0x03AAFB, 0x03A7FC, 0x03A3FB, 0x049FFC, 0x049AFB, 0x0498FC, 0x0592FE, 0x028FFB, 0x038BFB, 0x0389FC, 0x0586FD, 0x0482FB, 0x047EFB, 0x047EFD, 0x057CFE, 0x0277FB, 0x0474FC, 0x0671FD, 0x056BFC, 0x0468FC, 0x0468FE, 0x0466FF, 0x0361FE, 0x035BFB, 0x0659FD, 0x0354FB, 0x0354FD, 0x0654FE, 0x034FFA, 0x064EFA, 0x054AFD, 0x0446FC, 0x0343FC, 0x0442F9, 0x043EF7, 0x043BF7, 0x0338FA, 0x0536FD, 0x0633FE, 0x042FFA, 0x042DFB, 0x0528FC, 0x0223FA, 0x0420FD, 0x061FFF, 0x041CFC, 0x0517FD, 0x0415FB, 0x0412FB, 0x0410FC, 0x040DFC, 0x0509FE, 0x0507FC, 0x0203FB, 0x0201FC, 0x0402FD, 0x0601FD, 0x0600FE, 0x0302FD, 0x0402FD, 0x0801FC, 0x0B02FD,
     0x0E02FA, 0x1502FC, 0x1A01FD, 0x1C01FC, 0x1C02FB, 0x2003FD, 0x2303FC, 0x2601FC, 0x2A01FB, 0x2B02FC, 0x2C02FC, 0x3001FD, 0x3201FB, 0x3801FC, 0x3A02FB, 0x3E03FD, 0x4201FB, 0x4601FC, 0x4A02FC, 0x4D02FD, 0x4D02FB, 0x4E02FA, 0x5202F7, 0x5501F7, 0x5B00FB, 0x5E02FB, 0x6303FB, 0x6502FB, 0x6701FA, 0x6802FB, 0x6B02FC, 0x6A01FC, 0x6C02FC, 0x7002FB, 0x7502FD, 0x7B02FD, 0x8002FC, 0x8401FC, 0x8602FD, 0x8902FE, 0x8D02FD, 0x8D02FD, 0x8F03FC, 0x9102FC, 0x9402FB, 0x9801FC, 0x9B02FB, 0x9E03FD, 0xA302FD, 0xA500FA, 0xAC03FE, 0xAC02FB, 0xAE01FB, 0xB203FC, 0xB500FB, 0xBC02FD, 0xBD00FC, 0xC001FE, 0xC403FE, 0xC502FC, 0xC602FA, 0xCA02FB, 0xCD02FA, 0xCD02FA, 0xD402FB, 0xD702FC, 0xD902FD, 0xDD02FC, 0xE102FB, 0xE402FC, 0xE802FB, 0xEC01FC, 0xED00FC, 0xF202F9, 0xF601FE, 0xF603F5, 0xF601FF, 0xF704F6, 0xFA02F9, 0xFD02F0, 0xFD02ED, 0xFD01F4, 0xFC00F3, 0xFC04DF, 0xFD00F1, 0xFC03DB, 0xFC03DB, 0xFC01E2, 0xFD02DD, 0xFC03CF, 0xFB01D5, 0xFD02CB, 0xFD03C9, 0xFD02CE, 0xFD03BD, 0xFC01C0, 0xFC02BE, 0xFB01BA, 0xFB02B4, 0xFD02B3, 0xFD02B3, 0xFC01B2, 0xFC02AE, 0xFC02AC, 0xFC01A9, 0xFC01A6, 0xFC02A1, 0xFC039F, 0xFC039F, 0xFB029C, 0xFC0298, 0xFB0294, 0xFC018F, 0xFC018E};

void CycleColors()
{
    int lastElement = imageData.back(); // Save the last element
    imageData.pop_back();               // Remove the last element
    imageData.push_front(lastElement);  // Insert the last element at the front
}

void rainbow(HDC hdc, int x, int y, int IMAGE_WIDTH)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih = {0};
    bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmih.biWidth = IMAGE_WIDTH;
    bmih.biHeight = -1;
    bmih.biPlanes = 1;
    bmih.biBitCount = 32;
    bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 15;
    bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 5;

    BITMAPINFO dbmi = {0};
    dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;

    std::vector<int> imageDataVector(imageData.begin(), imageData.end());

    StretchDIBits(hdc, x, y, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1,
                  0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1,
                  reinterpret_cast<const void *>(imageDataVector.data()), &dbmi, 0, SRCCOPY);
}

// main function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lparam);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    TCHAR appname[] = TEXT("Template");
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;

    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = appname;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;

    // check this window class is registered or not
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Window class is not registered"), TEXT("Error...."), MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindow(appname,  // window name
                        appname,  // window text
                        WS_POPUP, // set POPUP window style for no border & controls
                        100,      // window position x
                        100,      // window position y
                        WIDTH,    // width
                        HEIGHT,   // height
                        NULL,
                        NULL,
                        hInstance,
                        NULL);

    // show & update created window
    SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 1, NULL); // Set a timer to trigger every 100ms
    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // get message from queue
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}

// WndProc function
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    HINSTANCE hIns;
    HWND exit_button, title;
    static int X, Y;
    LRESULT move = NULL;
    RECT rc;

    switch (message)
    {

    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        exit_button = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_BITMAP,
                                   250, 440, 76, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)100, hIns, 0);
        HBITMAP exitImg = (HBITMAP)LoadImageA(GetModuleHandleA(nullptr), (LPCSTR) "C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\test\\Resource\\Bitmap_112.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);

        title = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), TEXT("Hello"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, 120, 150, 120, 20, hwnd, 0, hIns, 0);
        SendMessageW(exit_button, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)exitImg);
        // SendMessageW(gen_button, BM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)genImg);
    }

    break;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        Membitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
        SelectObject(hdcMem, Membitmap);

        rainbow(hdcMem, 0, 50, 300);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top,
        hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        DeleteObject(Membitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);        
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
    }

    case WM_TIMER:
        CycleColors();
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        return 0;
        break;

    case WM_COMMAND:

        switch (wParam)
        {
        case 100:
            PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            return 0;
        }

        break;

        // size
    case WM_SIZE:
        X = LOWORD(lParam);
        Y = HIWORD(lParam);
        break;

        // move window
    case WM_NCHITTEST:
        RECT rc;
        POINT pt;

        GetCursorPos(&pt);

        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rc);
        rc.bottom = rc.bottom - 466;

        // if cursor position is within top layered drawn rectangle then
        // set move to HTCAPTION for moving the window from its client
        if (pt.x <= rc.right && pt.x >= rc.left && pt.y <= rc.bottom && pt.y >= rc.top)
        {
            move = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            if (move == HTCLIENT)
            {
                move = HTCAPTION;
            }
        }

        return move;

        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


Use two bitmaps (and two DC's): One that you draw into, and one that is displayed. Once you finished drawing in the first, blit the draw-bitmap into the display DC.

@Someprogrammerdude you don't need 2 bitmaps, 1 will suffice in this example. Draw the rainbow onto an in-memory bitmap, and have the WM_TIMER handler update that bitmap and invalidate the window. Then in the WM_PAINT handler, draw the current bitmap as-is onto the paint hdc. The WM_PAINT message may (and likely will) happen multiple times between WM_TIMER messages, so the in-memory bitmap needs to be preserved between messages.

Also, your background brush is black, so the system will fill the window with black before you start painting. Use a null brush or handle the WM_ERASEBKGND message

@RemyLebeau I created a in memory bitmap but its stuttering more. I have updated the code.

Consider including WS_CLIPCHILDREN in the window styles for the parent window.

Do like this:
void rainbow(HDC hdc, int x, int y, int IMAGE_WIDTH)
{
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih = {0};
    bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmih.biWidth = IMAGE_WIDTH;
    bmih.biHeight = -1;
    bmih.biPlanes = 1;
    bmih.biBitCount = 32;
    bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
    bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 15;
    bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 5;

    BITMAPINFO dbmi = {0};
    dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;

    std::vector<int> imageDataVector(imageData.begin(), imageData.end());

    HDC hmemdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc) ;
    HBITMAP hbmpmem = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, bmih.biWidth, 1) ;
    SelectObject(hmemdc, (HGDIOBJ) hbmpmem) ;

    StretchDIBits(hmemdc, x, y, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1,
                  0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1,
                  reinterpret_cast<const void *>(imageDataVector.data()), &dbmi, 0, SRCCOPY);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1, hmemdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteObject((HGDIOBJ)hbmpmem);
    DeleteDC(hmemdc);
}


doesnt render the rainbow

can you share the whole code, im using mingw (gcc 13).

link

thank you, i spent hours fixing this.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
